# SQL Query to find total weight

Tags: sql, algorithm

I have 30 records in a table having column "box number" and "weight".
I have to find 20 boxes out of 30 boxes  whose sum of weight is nearest to 1000 kg.

Comment: What sql engine do you use? BTW search for `knapsack problem sql` for some tips, because it won't be trivial :)

Comment: Why do you need to use SQL? A programming language is better suited for problems such as this. Your question is missing [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements). Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for [samples](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/90955/ you have plenty to play with. More or less on middle of the page the Knapsack problem solution is aproached on different ways, one should fit your needs.

Comment: Please tag the question with a tag indicating the server. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you read about the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server:

```
select TOP 20 box_number 
from t_boxes 
group by box_number 
order by ABS(SUM(box_weight) - 1000) ASC
```

Edit:
In case I misunderstood your question and you actually want to solve knapsack problem.
This is something that you really should do in SQL, but you can read [this](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/02/22/and-now-for-a-completely-inappropriate-use-of-sql-server/) article with very appropriate name: **And now for a completely inappropriate use of SQL Server**.

Answer (score 0):

The way you would solve this in SQL is not recommended, and may not even be feasible on any machine.  But, you can express the brute force solution as:

```
select box1.id, box2.id, . . . ,
       (box1.weight + box2.weight + . . .)
from box box1 join
     box box2
     on box2.id > box1.id join
     box box3
     on box3.id > box2.id join
     box box4
     on box4.id > box3.id
     . . .
     box box20
     on box20.id > box19.id
order by abs(1000 - (box1.weight + box2.weight + . . .))
```

The "on" conditions guarantee that you are looking at each set of boxes once, ordered by their unique ids.  The use of "join" rather than "left join" ensures that you end up with exactly 20 boxes.